# How to keep production and development git branches with different variables from conflicting with eachother?

Tags: git, version-control, branch, development-environment

We have one git repository serving two environments/branches: production and development.
The code between those two environments should be identical except for a few variables.

To exemplify:

in our development environment which exists in a separate network, we run a dhcp server
with configurations that match its IP space e.g. 192.168.1.0/24.
Say during boot a device needs to get `fileA` from 192.168.1.10, the dhcp has these options and sends it to the device.

If everything works fine we want to implement the exact same thing in production.
However production lives in e.g. 172.16.1.0/24.
So now the dhcp should send the same option to get `fileA` but from 172.16.1.10.

So now we have in the dhcp config file:

Production:
`get fileA from 172.16.1.10`

Development
`get fileA from 192.168.1.10`

Say we are currently in development and want to get `fileB` instead, after changing that line to `get fileB from 192.168.1.10` and deduced it works, we want to implement it in production.

However when we would merge dev into production we would overwrite not only fileA to fileB but also the IP address which we don't want. Other times it would give merge conflicts.

Also the interface, gateway, subnet and dhcp pool address would be changed.

A solution could be to do a search and replace but having to do that after every merge is quite cumbersome.

Another thing I thought of is to replace the actual ip address with variables:
`get fileA from $IP`
and fill in this variable from a config file with a search and replace.
This would be in development we would run the script to apply the variables, check if it's working and revert everything except the changes we made to be able to merge cleanly into production.

What would be the best way to tackle something like this?

Comment: See [this Git FAQ](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Git_FAQ#How_do_I_tell_Git_to_ignore_tracked_files.3F)

Comment: Hi @torek thanks for your reply, however I'm not facing the issue of untracking / not tracking an environment file between branches. The files should be tracked as I need to pull the changes that are made.

Comment: Yes, but it's ultimately the same *problem:* you want different configurations. Don't store them in commits. (Branch names don't matter, only commits matter.)

Comment: That would still mean that I would have to change e.g. `fileA` to `fileB` in both branches manually, right? And if there are more changes I would have to diff it and apply the changes to the other branch.

Comment: Well, you wouldn't change anything in *any* **branch** (or commit). You'd just have a not-in-Git file that controls this.

Comment: I think I understand what you're saying. In our case we would than have almost identical files on our production and development machines which are not tracked by git.
But the change I apply to development I would also have to do in production manually on those specific files which aren't tracked.